# How to request a trace with google cloud-trace

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, appstats, google-cloud-trace

Google Cloud has a powerful tracing tool for analyzing latency of requests and RPCs.   But it seems to just *pick* some requests that it finds deserving of traces.  Sometimes that's good enough, you can just browse through existing traces.   But if you are working on a performance enhancement, you want the trace on your particular query right now, you don't want to wait until it is deemed interesting.

Questions are

- What rules intervene in deciding which queries are traced ?
- Is there a way to *ask for* traces to be captured for a given URI ?

Either from within developer console, or by calling some API from within our application ?   Or through some app.yaml configuration ?   Or do we have to just wait and pray for the great algorithm to chose our request ?

Answer (score 5):

You can force tracing of a HTTP request by setting the cloud trace context header properly:

```
$ curl -H "X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 01234567890123456789012345678901;o=1" http://<your-app>.appspot.com/<path>
```

`01234567890123456789012345678901` (32 hex characters) is the trace id. You want to use a different one each time.
`o=1` enables tracing.

Use the following URL to view the trace (last part is the trace id):
http://console.developer.google.com/traces/details/01234567890123456789012345678901

Comment: Documented here: https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/faq#how_do_i_force_a_request_to_be_traced

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in particular request, why don't you use appstats? 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats?hl=en you can make performance enchancement, turn appstats on and deploy it to different version and have some control from appengine_config.py

I use cloud trace to get aggregate analysis, to get into more detail per request basis, I always use appstats as it contains more information.

Answer (score 1):

> > What rules intervene in deciding which queries are traced ?

Currently there is a sampling rate that guides which request are traced. The requests are sampled at a small number of requests per second per instance.

> > Is there a way to ask for traces to be captured for a given URI ?

The following could possibly help depending on your scenario.

You could add a Trace Context to force the request to force tracing on the request. Trace Context is essentially a HTTP header (X-Cloud-Trace-Context)

Here is an pointer to help inject a Trace Context: https://github.com/liqianluo/gcloud-trace-java/blob/master/cloud-trace-sdk-java-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/trace/sdk/TraceContext.java

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow and not sure of the nuances and subtleties of participating in this forum. But I build this tool being described above in the question. So was merely trying to help.

Comment: @patb - Could you tell me a little more about your scenario please? I would love to understand what you are doing? My suggestion above may unblock you.